# Dúvida no padding bottom

Tags: css

Alguém sabe o ERRO desse código? o paddim bottom simplesmente não funciona... obrigada

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Olá, me chamo Ana</title>
    
    <style>
      body{
        font-family: Arial;
      }
      .caixa1 {
        padding-top: 80px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
      }  


      .caixa2 {
        background: #7134eb;
        height: 300px;
      }  
      .caixa3 {
        height: 300px;
      }  

       h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 48px;
      }

       p {
        text-align: center
       }

       img{
         height: 150px;
       }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="caixa1">
      <h1> LIA </h1>

      <p> Testando </p>
      

      <img src="catioro.jpg">

    <div class="caixa2">Caixa 2</div>
    <div class="caixa3">Caixa 3</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Funciona sim! está aplicando normalmente, vc pode conferir https://prnt.sc/trgaus

Comment: Parece estar funcionando, mas note que sua `<div class="caixa1">`  não tem um fim `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se de fechar a sua `<div class="caixa1"></div>` de modo que o padding-bottom  "margem interna" esteja no local que deseja, do contrário seu navegador pode estar fechando ela automaticamente antes do final da página ou ainda antes da div.caixa2

Comment: Opa, não entendi...obrigada